# Easy question about compactly contained sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $U\subseteq X$ be a an open set of a topological space $X$ and $V\subset\subset U$ an open, compactly contained set (*i.e*, $\bar{V}$ is compact and $\bar{V}\subset U$).

When we say the closure of $V$ is compact, is it relative to the relative topology of $U$ or the topology of the whole space?

Comment: That's the same as open subset in $U$ are given by $U\cap W$, where $W$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter, since $U$ is open. Any open cover relative to $U$ is also an open cover relative to $X$, and any open cover relative to $X$ can be converted to an open cover relative to $U$ by taking intersections. So $\overline{V}$ is compact relative to $U$ if and only if it is compact relative to $X$.

It is very important that $U$ is open here; this fails completely when $U$ is not open.